# Signing (Debug) doesn't include the beta-reports-active entitlement

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

During the try to setup signing settings of Xcode 8, I've got the following error for the development provision profile:

> Provisioning profile "XXX" doesn't include the beta-reports-active
>   entitlement.

recreation of the provision profiles doesn't help. I'm not quite sure if this type of profile needs beta-reports-active settings at all, as I saw other issues only AppStore profiles should use these settings.

I will appreciate any help

#### UPDATE:

AdHoc provision profile has the same error, however AppStore provision profile works fine for Release.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error while trying to make AdHoc distribution build from Xcode 9.0. By mistake I choose different provision profile in Signing(Distribution) and Signing(Release). As I made same provision for both, the error gone.

Hope this will help.

Thanks.

Comment: Same question, but not resolved by any method. Xcode does not have Signing(Distribution) item, how can it be here?

Answer (score 3):

I had set entitlements with beta-reports-active for debug and release configuration. After removal of the path to Debug entitlements error disappeared.

As written in the Apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1830/_index.html

> beta-reports-active is a new entitlement added to App Store profiles
>   in September 2014 to allow App Store code signed builds to be tested
>   using iTunes Connect

So it should not be set in the other builds.

Comment: Please, could you exactly describe, how do you removed the `path to Debgu entitlements` ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when was trying to export AdHoc build (though AppStore worked well).

The problem was solved by switching Provisioning Profile in project settings general tab, from AppStore config to AdHoc and archiving again.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when I was trying to export AdHoc build.

The problem was resolved by change Provisioning Profile in project settings general tab, from AppStore config to AdHoc and archiving again it works for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So the reason it happens is because when archiving `xcodebuild` is packaging provisioning profiles specified for the build configuration and updates `.xcent` for all binaries in `IntermediateBuildFilesPath` to match whatever is specified in those profiles.

For example, if you have multiple configurations, like beta and release, most likely you are specifying beta (ad-hoc w/o `beta-reports-active` in them) provisioning profiles for one and release (app-store w/ `beta-reports-active` in them) provisioning profiles for another one.

Then after you archived beta configuration, you will have an option to export archive for both - beta and release distribution (website and TestFlight) and `xcodebuild` won't throw this error because used provisioning profiles are missing `beta-reports-active` and when it will sign for App Store distribution (TestFlight, for example) it will pick up correct profiles (assuming you explicitly specified them in a plist passed to `-exportOptionsPlist`).

Now when you archived release configuration, the story is different. Now xcodebuild packaged provisioning profiles with a `beta-reports-active` flag and xcodebuild won't allow you to export (resign) with beta provisioning profiles for whatever reason. I think this is an actual xcodebuild bug.

Assuming all my assumptions and understanding of the error are correct, one should always use beta provisioning profiles when archiving, no matter which configuration, but export with a proper profiles later.

Answer (score 0):

```
No matching provisioning profiles found for "your.app" 
None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified 
entitlements: beta-reports-active.
```

beta-reports-active is a new entitlement added to App Store profiles 
[Apple doc state.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1830/_index.html)

> NOTE: "Validate" and "Submit" features on the Xcode Organizer
>   Archives tab require an App Store provisioning profile. Therefore,
>   Validate or Submit is not intended to be used with Development, Ad Hoc
>   or Enterprise builds. Ad Hoc or Enterprise distributions should skip
>   straight to Export.

1. On the Certs IDs & Profiles website > Provisioning Profiles page,
   click the App Store profile. Click 'Edit' Click 'Generate' To create
   a new App Store profile, click the "+" button on the Distribution
   Provisioning Profiles page.
2. After creating or updating your App Store profile, do one of the
   following to install the updated profile in Xcode:
3. Click 'Download' and drag/drop the provisioning profile onto the
   Xcode icon on the dock Click '↺' on Xcode > Preferences > Accounts >
   (your account) > View Details pane

*In my case, it happened when my teammate created a new distribution certificate and provision profile. It worked fine when I deleted existing invalid certificates(shown with red error mark) from "Keychain Access"
Also, check if release and debug schemes are using respective signing identities.*

Answer (score 0):

In My case, using xcode 9.2 the solution was using old build method, not the new one to archive my project. 
Probably is the thing on Apple xCode that's not polished at all, it seems neither in 9.3 but I don't know if you can select method in 9.3. 
I read that it was solved on 9.4.

Answer (score -1):

Let me tell you the correct answer.
Xcode archive with Release packages by default, when you export development version with Release package will show thie error.
We should archive Debug package changing this in schemes option and then export development version. KO!^_^

Answer (score -2):

Regenerate your Provisional profile will solve this problem. To regenerate your Provisional Profile follow the following step.

On the *Certs IDs & Profiles website > Provisioning Profiles* page, click the App Store profile.

*Click 'Edit'*

*Click 'Generate'*

Rebuild your app using newly created provisional profile and Archive it.
Visit [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1830/_index.html)